# Integral involving fractional part

Tags: integration

I stumbled across this problem:

> Let $$
> \int_0^9e^x\left(1+\left\{x\right\}+\left\{x\right\}^2\right)dx=J$$ and
> $$\int_0^1e^x\left(1+\left\{x\right\}+\left\{x\right\}^2\right)dx=I$$ If $\frac JI=\sum_{n=0}^k e^n$, then find $k$

Here $\left\{x\right\}$ represents the fractional part function. I decomposed it as $\left\{x\right\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor $,( where $\lfloor x\rfloor $ is the floor of $x$ or its round-down), but found the integral to be too lenghty, Finally, I solved it to get $k=8$.

I am looking for some shorter/elegant/intuitive approach for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{J}{I}$ instead of $\frac{I}{J}$? It doesn't work out as it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imagine the graph of $f(x)=e^x(1+\{x\}+\{x\}^2)$, it consists of the very similar-looking continuous parts on the segments of the form $[k, k+1]$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. More specificially, to get from the graph of this function on the segment $[k-1, k]$ the graph on the segment $[k, k+1]$, you move the graph rightward to 1 and multiply (stretch) it by $e$. This is because $(1+\{x\}+\{x\}^2)$ member is unchanged upon $x\mapsto x+1$, while $e^x$ converts to $e^{x+1}$ which is always $e$ times higher.

This means that the area under the graph is $e$ times more for each subsequent segment, so that $J=I+eI+e^2I+\cdots+e^8I$ if you decompose $J$ into the sum of 9 integrals over segments of length 1. This is exactly (well, I assume it is $J/I$ not $I/J$) the formula below with $k=8$.

Answer (score 0):

To get a shorter answer know that the fractional part function is periodic over 1, meaning $\left\{x+1\right\}=\left\{x\right\}$
so we can use this property to rewrite $J$ as:
$$J=\sum _{n=0}^8\:\int _{\:n}^{n+1}e^x\left(1+\left\{x\right\}+\left\{x\right\}^2\right)dx$$
Using the substitution $x=u+n$ we get:
$$J=\sum _{n=0}^8\:\int _{\:0}^{1}e^{u+n}\left(1+\left\{u+n\right\}+\left\{u+n\right\}^2\right)du$$
Since $\left\{x\right\}=\left\{x+1\right\}=\left\{x+2\right\}=...=\left\{x+n\right\} : n\in \mathbb{N}$
We get:
$$J=\sum _{n=0}^8\:\int _{\:0}^{1}e^{n}e^{u}\left(1+\left\{u\right\}+\left\{u\right\}^2\right)du$$
$$J=\sum _{n=0}^8\:e^{n}I=I\sum _{n=0}^8\:e^{n}$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{J}{I}=\sum _{n=0}^8\:e^{n}$$